# Manipulate string in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to manipulate a set of strings in R.

The data I have:

```
Data         Field
Mark Twain   5
```

I want it to instead be:

```
Data        Field
Twain Mark  5
```

My idea was to first split the string into two columns and then concatenate. But I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: `paste(strsplit('Mark Twain', ' ')[[1]][c(2,1)], collapse = ' ')`

Comment: `paste(strsplit(as.character(df$Data), ' ')[[1]][c(2,1)], collapse = ' ')´ if I have multiple strings right?

Comment: You'll need to loop over the list `strsplit` will produce: `sapply(strsplit(df$Data, ' '), function(x){paste(x[c(2,1)], collapse = ' ')})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this approach:

```
> df <- data.frame(Data=c("Mark Twain"), Field=5)
> df$Data <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Data), " "), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=" "))
> df
        Data Field
1 Twain Mark     5
```

This will work even if the number of rows in your data frame is > 1

Answer (score 0):

we can use `sub` to do this

```
df1$Data <- sub("(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)", "\\2 \\1", df1$Data)
df1
#        Data Field
#1 Twain Mark     5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Data = "Mark Twain", Field = 5L),
.Names =   c("Data", "Field"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```